# Links in WordPress post not output as links

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site and links in my latest blog posts are not getting output in the front end as links.

Dashboard showing link is set, please find the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

the page for the above screenshot post is at http://sportsmailonline.co.uk/football/young-hearts-walk-free/

I am running

- WP: 4.4.2
- Avada: 3.9.3

**Plugins**

- Gravity Forms
- Fusion Core
- Easy Fancybox
- Revslider

Comment: have you tried it with the text editor instead of the visual editor?

Comment: Perhaps you just forgot to click the Update button? Or maybe your stylesheet is making links look like ordinary text. It's rather difficult to debug from screenshots.

Comment: I have tried with the text editor only with no different results.

Comment: I have had a look at the HTML output for the and no a tags are output for the link so CSS is not masking it.

Comment: Will you please try to to set link in any other demo post for testing purpose. If your link working on demo post then we figure out something goes wrong on you that post.

Comment: I have copied this over to a new post adding the link in manually via the WordPress editor and in HTML on the text view but with no change. The link is still not shown in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

It is rendered correctly on the page you supplied.

```
<a href="http://www.thefa.com/my-football/justplay/">Just Play Website</a>
```

Only problematic thing is that the link color seems to be too close to the text color. If you want to highlight links you would need to change the css of your page:

you have:

```
body a, body a::after, body a::before {
    color: #72849C;
}
```

change that to a more different color than the text color, like:

```
body a, body a::after, body a::before {
    color: #00BFFE;
}
```

There might also be an option in your theme's settings to change link / text colors